# MongoDB .net API ClientSettings Credentials Obsolete in v2.5

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I've used use Credentials like:

```
Credentials = new[] { MongoCredential.CreateCredential("aserver", "dbuser", "userpwd"), MongoCredential.CreateCredential("bserver", "dbuser", "userpwd") }
```

when new a MongoClientSettings ojbect. but in new [version 2.5](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/Properties_T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClientSettings.htm) the is a new property Credential and mark Credentials is Obsolete.

Here is my questions:

1.How could "Credential" property receive more than one login as I used before? I've tried use string or multi "Credential", tested failed.

2.I kept using obsoleted "Credentials", will it disabled in next version?